# NSNotification observer in custom UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm building an app with iPod-like controls (play, pause, etc). The app has tableView with track names in each cell. I have a `MainViewController` with a `UITableView` and a custom `UITableViewCell` class. The player controls exist in the `MainViewController`.

I also have a play/pause button in each cell. I've successfully set up `NSNotifications` to post a notification when the play button is pressed in the cell, so the track info is sent to the observer and responder method in `MainViewController` and the player controls (driven by `MPMoviePlayerController`) is initiated.

This works, but once the track is playing, I can't figure out how to make the play/pause button in the cell "mirror" the state of the play/pause button in my iPod controls. I don't think adding a `NSNotification observer` in every cell is the correct way of doing this.

Additional info: The play/pause button image in the `MainViewController` player is determined by a method that fires every half second and checks the `playbackstate` of the `MPMoviePlayerController`. If playing, the player button set's the play image. If paused, it set's the pause image. I'm thinking the implementation to also set the tableCell play/pause button will go here.

**Edit** This method is called whenever the playback state changes (via NSNotification), within my UITableViewController. (`playButton` is the play/pause button in the player controls, not the play/pause in the table cell in which I'm trying to update according to playback state).

```
- (void) updateViewForPlayerState
{
// Change playButton image depending on playback state
[playButton setImage:((moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying) ? pauseBtnBG : playBtnBG) forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[tableView reloadData]` when your state changed and on providing a cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` set the button according to the state of your data (i.e whether the song that cell refers to is playing or not).

Also instead of notifications you could use delegation which is the usual approach. But notifications also work especially if you need multiple observers.

Comment: Is it expensive to call `reloadData` every time the playback state changes?

Comment: `reloadData` only reloads the data for visible cells. So this approach is efficient.

Answer (score 2):

A Great example for what you are trying to do is available on the apple development site.

[TableViewSuite](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318)

The project in question is called CustomTableViewCell. This project uses a Timer to periodically update the cells, which from your description it sounds like your are doing something similar.

When the state of the cell changes do the following.

1. Update the state of the cell. I am assuming this is reflected in plabackstate
2. call [cell setNeedsDisplay]

That should force the custom cell to redraw itself with the new state that you have set.

This would be in your table view controller in the timer callback method

```
NSArray *visibleCells = self.tableView.visibleCells;
    for (CustomCell *cell in visibleCells) {
        [cell redisplay];
}
```

This would be in your custom table view cell

```
- (void)redisplay {
    [customCellView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: I don't completely understand your solution. By using `setNeedsDisplay`, do I need to have a `drawRect` method in my custom cell? I've added some code to my question.

Comment: With your solution, where would I change the cell play/pause button image?

Comment: @mnort I assumed that you did have a custom cell in your solution that was using drawRect. How are you allocating the cell?

Comment: My issue was bit different but your "NSArray *visibleCells = self.tableView.visibleCells;" works for me. Thank you. +1